# Transparency texture display incorrectly

Tags: three.js

I create a mesh with transparency texture over the ground. but when I move the mesh, the transparent part of the texture changed to the background color of the scene somewhere. how to solve this problem? am I missing some configuration here?

**mainCode:**

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true,alpha: true,logarithmicDepthBuffer:true});
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide,color: 0xFFFFFF,map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(_background),transparent: true,opacity: 1,});
```

[image: screenshot of the bug]

Comment: why you write `opacity: 1,`? means you have one extra `,`  provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Answer (score 0):

set `depthTest:false` in [material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.depthTest)

**means :**

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true,alpha: true,logarithmicDepthBuffer:true});
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide,color: 0xFFFFFF,map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(_background),transparent: true,opacity: 1,depthTest:false});
```